# How can I get Cortana to change a reminder time using voice commands?

Tags: cortana

I used Cortana to set up a reminder and now I want to change the time of that reminder. The touch interface allows me to do this but how I can I do this through voice commands?

Comment: Is there a way to change all reminders at once? I had routed a list of eight place-based errands. I'd like to change them to tomorrow without manually editing each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Unfortunately changing reminder time verbally is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Cortana can change your appointments on the fly. If you remember you have an appointment at 12 next day, just say “**Change tomorrows appointment at 12**” and then follow up to change time. BTW, Cortana can also tell you the conflicts when you are changing appointments.

Comment: The question is about reminders, not appointments.